# How should the President of the United States handle mass media organizations that discredit him/her?

Tags: united-states, president, freedom-of-speech

Presidential administrations in the recent past have fought a very public political battle of words with the media in the United States. The media is a very powerful entity with the power to sway public opinion--not just inform! To the public, these political battles between the media and the President may seem divisive--but to be fair, the media does often seem to take political sides, downplaying one party and promoting another.

How is the President--as Commander In Chief of our armed forces--legally permitted to handle his/her disagreements with the media? Is s/he also in fact fully entitled to the same free speech and free press rights as any other member of the public? Is s/he free to attack the media publicly, despite the office?

Comment: Are you asking if the President has limited freedom of speech as a member of the armed forces?

Comment: I don't believe he can be counted as a member of the armed forces. I'm just wondering what, if any, special, lawful provisions or restrictions there might be for his own rights because of his office.

Comment: Why on earth do you think such special provisions targeting just the president would exist... And your final question "where does it state that" is totally unclear what it refers to.

Comment: @Fizz, remember: "ShieldOfSalvation is a new contributor to this site. Take care in asking for clarification, commenting, and answering. Check out our Code of Conduct." When I asked, "where does it state that," I'm referring to whether there is some legal document that makes any such provision or restriction.

Comment: "Such provision" as in explicitly allowing him to berate the media? Because you begin that (long) sentence with "I believe the answer is yes"... which again is not very clear what you're answering in the affirmative, but presumably it's the title question, so you're saying he's free to berate the media, and then ask for an "it" that states that... where "that" is the positive affirmation that he is allowed to berate the media? I'm sure you've heard of the First Amendment since you were able to find the more intricate US codes.

Comment: Downvoted because of the bias evident in the term "left-leaning communications agencies".  What you mean is news media, which in general are companies.  Nor are they particularly left-leaning in general: for instance, Trump has recently been quite critical of the Wall Street Journal, which could hardly be described as "left-leaning" :-)

Comment: I specifically said "left-leaning" because it is a well-known and documented fact that this is what our present administration is very clearly and publicly targeting. It was just brought up as an example. However, in other periods it could have as well been the opposite. That's neither here nor there. I've tried to keep this discussion as non-biased as possible and have not promoted any sides.

Comment: I really don't see how the quoted passage on military policy prohibiting criticism of officials has anything to do with a civilian criticizing the press.

Comment: I've tried to make my question as neutral as possible and removed any wording that would make it seem as if I'm rooting for one party or another. That was never what this was about. I think the question is definitely on a lot of people's minds considering the current drama playing out on TV nowadays and this generation's general lack of knowledge about our country's foundations and its history. It bears asking. IT SHOULD NOT BE CLOSED as "off-topic". It deserves a simple, logical answer that this StackExchange group in particular is qualified to give.

Comment: @jamesqf: that was somewhat prescient https://www.wsj.com/articles/what-trump-has-in-common-with-napoleon-11588784608 :0 I wonder what the reactions to that will be given what happened last time https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/492084-trump-slams-wsj-for-failing-to-mention-ratings-in-critical-editorial

Comment: @Fizz: Unfortunaterly that WSJ article is paywalled.

Comment: @ShieldOfSalvation: The problem with your question is that it can't really be neutral or non-political, because no other US President (at least in my lifetime) has had the same sort of relationship with the press as the current one.  AFAIK, no other President ever used the term "fake news", which Trump claims to have invented. (He's lying: https://www.washingtonian.com/2019/10/02/trump-claims-he-invented-the-term-fake-news-an-interview-with-the-guy-who-actually-helped-popularize-it/ )  Trump discredits himself: the news media simply do their job and report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly a Free Speech or Freedom of the Press issue; both might apply to, I quote, ‘mass media organizations that discredit [the President]’.

The wording of the First Amendment to the US Constitution is:

> **Congress shall make no law** respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; **or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press;** or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.

That’s it, that’s the Amendment.

The highlighted parts are everything that is written on Free Speech and Freedom of the Press. There is no provision within this Amendment that would imply it does not extend its protection to government officials. There is no distinction made between government speech, corporate speech and private speech. In fact, there is sufficient evidence to assume that [Freedom of the Press also applies to non-commercial publishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_the_press_in_the_United_States#21st_century) (see also references therein).

There do exist [Restrictions to the Freedom of Speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_free_speech_exceptions); again, these generally apply to anyone assuming the category is accurate. One such group of restrictions is centred around employers being able to restrict their employees speech while said employee is acting as an employee. This does, in principle, apply to government employees. However, the President is head of the Executive Branch and as such *defines* the direction they want the government to take. Thus, assuming they remain within other restrictions that apply to anyone, the President is not subject to any further restrictions of their speech.

One key restriction the President, the news media and anyone else is subject to is [False Statement of Fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_statements_of_fact): As there is ‘no constitutional value in false statements of fact’ such statements can be subject to civil or criminal liability, if the plaintiff can prove at least negligence on the defendant’s side (see [Gertz v. Robert Welch, Inc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gertz_v._Robert_Welch,_Inc.)). So neither the President nor the news media are permitted to willfully and knowingly lie about the other side.

However, as a public figure the President (but not necessarily the news media, as far as I understand) is subject to increased standards of suing for defamation as established in [New York Times Co v. Sullivan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Times_Co._v._Sullivan). It requires public figures to prove [Actual Malice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actual_malice) when attempting to sue for defamation, that is:

> with knowledge that it was false or with reckless disregard of whether it was false or not.

So without proving that a news medium *knowingly* published a falsehood or did so with *reckless disregard* of its truthfulness, a President’s defamation case would be thrown out.

Concerning your explicit mentioning of the President being Commander in Chief: the [Due Process clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Due_Process_Clause) of the Fifth and Fourteenth Amendments likely prohibit any attempt of the Executive to infringe on freedoms the Constitution and its Amendments guarantee. Any and all action the President intends to take must follow normal due process. The President cannot unilaterally decide to briefly override the First Amendment for whatever reason.

Answer (score 17):

The president is not a member of the military, and not subject to military rules of order. Technically speaking, he has the same rights as any private individual in the US to publicly express personal opinions (within the boundaries of slander and libel laws). In fact, the president has a distinct role in setting US policy and making political decisions that requires him to use and convey his own judgement. Most US presidents have spent much of their administration using cultured and curated expressions of their own opinions to craft public consensus and motivate political action. The [Bully Pulpit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bully_pulpit) was a long presidential tradition even before Teddy Roosevelt coined the term.

That being said, the traditional expectation has been that US presidents will express themselves in a cultured and curated fashion, with the goal of building consensus rather than spreading discord. The constitution specifies the president must be 35 years old specifically because the founders felt that younger people would be too intemperate: too aggressive, too hasty, too combative, too ideological, etc. It was their impression that by 35 a person develops a certain calm, sober, critical perspective — not being given to flights of fancy or strong egoic reactions — and that the electoral process would tend to select the most high functioning of that 'mature' group. Historically this has been the case, more or less, and while past presidents may have varied greatly on intelligence, articulateness, and political leanings, all have generally managed to separate their role as *president* from their role as *private citizen*, drawing a strict line between personal matters (likes, dislikes, squabbles and friendships) and those opinions needed for giving direction to public policy.

Unfortunately, Trump has not conformed to this tradition. He does not seem to make any distinction between public and private affairs, often airing his private grievances as though they were matters of public concern, or turning matters of public concern into personal issues of his own success or the failures of others. He is notably intemperate, and reacts from the gut rather than any sober consideration of facts and contexts. He attacks the media because — unlike his predecessors — he does not try to build consensus around policy; he demands that others agree with his opinions, and punishes those who disagree as disloyal.

Breaking with traditional institutions is not a criminal offense, obviously. But that doesn't make it any less destructive to the nation as a whole.

Comment: Trump, quite simply, seems to be the proverbial boss from hell.  Pretty much anything in the book about how to manage and motivate groups of people is reversed.  I suspect (hope?) that, some time from now, people in the future will wonder how such *unpresidential behavior* ever kept traction rather than inviting ridicule.  It doesn't really matter what side of the political divide he sits on, this would be just as bad if it was coming from the left.  One thing to consider though is that mainstream channels like CNN and MSNBC *are* themselves getting to be Fox-like in terms of partisanship.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Why Trump's style? Because one cannot make an omelet without breaking some eggs. A large part of the USA population thinks that tings have to change, and after many failed attempts to do so using a softer approach, that part of the electorate judges that in the current situation a sledgehammer is needed. They don't disagree with you that Trump's style is blunt and unconventional; They just think this style is a useful tool to get anything changed at all. (opinions clearly differ on the "useful" part, though)

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: Let's not overflow the equivalence between Left and Right News media, here. Without suggesting that this is intrinsic to the camps, currently Left-leaning news outlets have an editorial bias on top of a basic conformance to facts, while Right-leaning news outlets have largely discarded facts in a persistent effort to re-write reality so it conforms to partisan ideology. That effect has been growing since the mid-1990s. Reality counts, you know...

Comment: @Sjoerd: Without disagreeing with your point, I need to raise the issue of 'rational' vs 'irrational' promotion of change. One does not, after all, break eggs with a sledgehammer. If a large portion of the US population wants something, and cannot achieve it politically over the course of decades, do they re-evaluate their goals and seek out rational compromise, or do they try to strong-arm their way into power and impose the rules they want on the majority? somewhere in that spectrum lies the difference between democratic governance and authoritarian regimes.

Comment: @TedWrigley Given that they used and followed the democratic procedures for elections, it's far-fetched to say they strong-armed their way into power.

Comment: @Sjoerd: democratic procedures like Gerrymandering, voter suppression, dark money? I mean, so far they have (mostly) avoided political assassination, so there's that. But still... At any rate, let's not have a partisan dispute.

Comment: mostly, yes.  but... CNN made a whole splash about Trump calling covid a hoax.  looking at the whole speech, he was his usual rambling self, but it seemed more like he was criticizing Dems for trying to find another issue to gripe about him, referring to their hoopla about covid as their new hoax.  not so much about covid being a hoax.  he's hard to parse, so who knows what's going on in that tiny brain?  but CNN willfully taking it out of context and claiming he directly called covid a hoax?  on multiple occasions?  I stopped watching CNN, switched to Reuters.  much better for it.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: CNN is not Trump's mother; it isn't their job to interpret what Trump *means* when he rambles; it's their job to report what Trump *says*. If Trump says something that can be taken in such a damaging way then it is their job to point out how damaging it can be to say that. If Trump doesn't like it, Trump can clean up his expressions so there isn't any ambiguity.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: I mean, does it really matter whether Trump thought that the virus was a hoax, or thought the Dems were just attacking him? Either scenario means that Trump is downplaying the risk of the virus (in the first case because he doesn't believe it, and in he second because he's squabbling politics), and the end result is the same. It's usually hard to tell whether someone is *actually* dumb or just *playing at* being dumb as a ploy, but dumb is as dumb does, and no one needs to dig into it further than that.

Comment: "has the same rights as any private individual in the US to publicly express personal opinions": except everything he says publicly is said "within the scope of his official duties" as president.

Comment: @phoog: Is it? Really? He and his supporters constantly deny that, you know, saying that he is just joking, or blowing off steam...

Comment: @TedWrigley see the justice department's filing in Carroll v. Trump.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers detailed it well enough. In summary, the President is legally allowed to say pretty much whatever they want, however they want, as long as they don't abridge their detractor's First Amendment rights.

However, the nuances of the President's interactions with others is solely a ***matter of opinion***, destined to change throughout the ages.

Those who use the term *presidential* reference the demeanor of the past century of presidents, though they often forget about the existence of legendary presidents like Andrew Jackson.

In my opinion, the difference between the demeanor of presidents in the past vs in the future will be how willing they are to air their private thoughts. As long as you keep listening to their daily ramblings, you will eventually come across a thought they had that you will not like.

Through Twitter, members of Congress connect with their bases, sling mud across the aisle, and generally air their thoughts to the public. This behavior will slide over to the presidency as if it were only natural.

But these are all digressions.

### What is the optimal response when mass media organizations discredit the POTUS?

It should not be forgotten at any moment that corporate news media profits from bad news and controversy. When interviewing people they disagree with, poor interviewers will cut in when the interviewee is speaking, attempt to constantly ask the same question to drive a point, put words in the interviewee's mouth, recite canned lines, all for the sake of a sound bite.

Compare this to even just *pretending* to be genial and open to discussion.

[An empathy-based approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3XR4QrJyxA) would be much more optimal and popular than that, which has understanding and respecting the perspective of others as a core concept.
When applied at scale on alternative media such as Youtube, this will resemble:

- providing detailed example cases for people to think about without asserting an answer, because people will come to their own conclusions.
- instead of passing down judgement, offering concrete strategies for improvement
- avoiding an incongruence between words and goals. People will recognize when you are being manipulative and fake.

Naturally, when these are your goals, it becomes a non-starter to even respond to emotionally-laden charges by news media corporations, because this does not lead to any positive directions. Any response will simply cause any bystanders to put their guard up and stop listening.